# Change filename of Bower dependencies

Tags: ember.js, bower

I've got an Ember app and want to use external libraries (like in my case gamps api). So I've put a dependency in my bower.json file which looks like that:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "gmaps-with-token": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX",
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, bower install will load a file called 'index' without any suffix. However importing that file in my ember-cli-app with `app.import(app.bowerDirectory + 'gmpas-width-token/index');`
won't work and I don't know why.
When I try to start the ember server, ember prompts

"*You must pass a file to 'app.import'. ...*"

Can anybody explain to me why this is a problem? Maybe it matters because of the missing file-suffix at the "index" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody explain me why this is a problem? Maybe its matters because of the missing file-suffix at the "index" file.

That's exactly what it is. Broccoli is expecting a file with a file-extension. I don't know why, but it assumes that a path with no extension is a directory. You need to ensure that the file has an extension. You can do one of two things for that:

1. Download the file manually and put it in your `vendor` folder. This will ensure it has an extension.
2. Create a bower shim by creating a repository that hosts the file (with an extension) then point bower at that repo instead of the Google Maps URL.

The first option will allow you to get up and running more quickly, so that might be the preferred option. You can always switch to the second option later if you need.

Comment: Thank you GJK, but now: How could I force bower than to add a file-suffix if doesnt exist in the source-file (let bower to download the file and save it to index.JS)

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood you. There's no suffix at the end of the file in the bower directory?

Comment: Sorry about that misunderstanding. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your helpfulness :)

Comment: I updated my answer. I did a quick check and it doesn't look like bower has a way to add an extension or rename that file when it downloads it. (Which isn't surprising, bower is pretty limited.) I think downloading the file and storing it somewhere is your only way.

Comment: Okay seems like there is no other way. thank you again :)